# problem to install packages in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: apt

```
fids@fids-NDiSM323:~$ java-version
java-version: command not found
fids@fids-NDiSM323:~$ java -versin
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
fids@fids-NDiSM323:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
[sudo] password for fids: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package default-jre is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java9-installer 9b111+9b111arm-1~webupd8~1
  oracle-java8-installer 8u77+8u77arm-1~webupd8~4
  oracle-java6-installer 6u45-0~webupd8~8
  oracle-java7-installer 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'default-jre' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install oracle-java-8-installer'. I think this was caused by the Webupd8 custom repository. Simply choose a version. I'd recommend the Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

You have typos here:

```
fids@fids-NDiSM323:~$ java -versin
```

It must be `java -version`

Then run this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

To install Oracle JDK 8:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Or execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

This will install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE). If you instead need the Java Development Kit (JDK), which is usually needed to compile Java applications (for example Apache Ant, Apache Maven, Eclipse and IntelliJ IDEA execute the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

That is everything that is needed to install Java.

Then run `java -version`